# Scripting for Public Calendars in Office 365

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365, adfs

We have about 10 onsite technicians who do breakfix work.  I would like to create a unified calendar that shows all of their appointments for the day, week and month without having to populate it manually.  We are using fully hosted Exchange in Office 365 and no longer have an on premise mail server.

How would you recommend accomplishing this/what would be the most logical implementation?  If I can't create a single unified calendar, could I use powershell to generate a report containing this information?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to script this or write an application to do it.

MessageOps makes a [PowerShell module for Exchange Web Services (EWS)](http://www.messageops.com/software/office-365-tools-and-utilities/messageops-exchange-ews-module/).

You could also [preview the REST APIs for Office 365](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn776319(v=office.15).aspx) and use those in conjunction with `Invoke-RestMethod` in PowerShell.

If you're looking for scripting specifics, I would definitely recommend posting on StackOverflow instead of here. If you end going that route, please send me a link to your question; it's interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook, you can very easily *view* multiple calendars. As long as you are allowed some level of "Read" access to the technician's calendar, just do that. No need to make an additional mailbox that would only exist simply to hold duplicates of other people's appointments.

Go to Calendar, "New Calendar Group", and populate it with your techs. Different versions of Outlook might have slightly different GUI options to do that.

That's the most logical way to do it: use the existing functionality. Also, depending on what you're doing, Free/Busy (most often seen when inviting people to new Appointments) can also show free and busy blocks of time.

/Edit based on your comment. Yes, you could use Powershell to hit Exchange Web Services. You could run a script, using an account that does have rights to view the calendar folders, to extract the events from specific mailboxes over a certain date range. You would then need to figure out the best way to display/format the events to meet your business needs.

Comment: That's how we're doing it now.  Unfortunately, that means in order to send out daily tech locations we need to copy and paste that information every morning and send it to a distro list.  People need that info, but shouldn't necessarily have full calendar access.  I'd like to automate this to get that time back.

Comment: OK, you didn't fully explain your desired scenario in your question. Please keep that in mind when posting questions: explain the real problem you're trying to solve, and things you've done that don't solve the problem as desired.

Comment: Although I don't understand one of your stated restrictions. "People need that info, but shouldn't necessarily have full calendar access." I didn't say full access : I said "Some level of "Read" access." You can get fairly granular with the permissions. If you are planning on doing a full export for others to see these calendars, there's no effective difference from giving those others "read" access to the Calendar folders in the first place. Either way, they'll be able to see all the same information.